# How can I operate on the active X display using a command in the console?

Tags: unity, compiz, command-line, xorg

I have problems where compiz freezes and I have to switch to another console(ctrl+alt+F1) to restart. But it would be easier if I could just do "$ compiz --replace" in the other console and not have to lose work or anything.

But when I do this it says it can't open the display, makes sense because the display is open in console 7. **Is there any way I can easily redirect a command to another console for it to be run there?**

Like for instance, be in console 1 and execute "$ compiz --replace" on console 7?

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple in theory and appears to work with `compiz --replace`, but other programs may not be so cooperative.

- Login to the console session after `Ctrl-Alt-F1`, and type:

  - `export DISPLAY=:0.0` (0 is the default display for the GUI/X)
- Followed by `compiz --replace`, etc.
- This simply sets the `DISPLAY` environment variable in your console session to that of your GUI session, hopefully fooling programs into thinking they are on that display and then *operating on that display*.

Comment: Is this safe to do for like later on in the active x or does this only effect that one console session?